# Validate and restart python for loop if validation is false

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Okay so I am trying to make the on-screen version of Mastermind color guessing game. It's human vs computer. Computer will randomly generate an array of 4 colors (from a list of 5 pre-defined colors). This selection will be hidden from user. Next, user will enter 4 color choices one by one. The game will tell user if color is correct and if its in the correct position by comparing it to system color array.

What I am not able to do is, If user enters a color that is not in the pre defined list, program should throw an error message `Wrong Color! Please try again` and loop should start again from that point.

Here's the code I've written:

```py
#User Defined Functions
def FetchColor(x):  #Function to take the randomly generated number, match it with color scheme and return the color based on scheme.
    if x <= 10 and x >= 1:
        temp_color = 'Red'
    
    if x <= 20 and x >= 11:
        temp_color = 'Green'

    if x <= 30 and x >= 21:
        temp_color = 'Blue'

    if x <= 40 and x >= 31:
        temp_color = 'Purple'

    if x <= 50 and x >= 41:
        temp_color = 'Yellow'

    return temp_color

def DisplayInfo():
    print()
    print("Please Enter Color: Red, Green, Blue, Purple, Yellow")
    print("NOTE: Colors are case sensitive (Enter Colour with First Letter Capital)")
    print()



#Color Scheme
#1-10 Red
#11-20 Green
#21-30 Blue
#31-40 Purple
#41-50 Yellow

#Introduction 



#System Part

import random

colors = ['','','',''] #Array to store System choosen colors

position = 0
num_guess = 0

for i in range(4):
    temp_color = ''
    temp_int = random.randint(1, 50) #Generate Random Integer
    color = FetchColor(temp_int) #Fetch the Color From Pre-Defined Scheme In the Function

    colors[position] = color #Add Generated Colors To Color Array
    position = position + 1 #increase position to edit next value

#print(colors)  #Uncomment this line when the game is in testing mode. This line will print the system choosen colors before executing the user part


#User Part

user_colors = ['','','',''] #Array to store colors user guess
DisplayInfo()

while user_colors != colors:
    user_colors = ['','','',''] #This ensures that array is empty if user is retrying. Otherwise there will be an outofbound exception.
    position2 = 0

    for z in range(4):
        usr_color = input('Guess The Color: ') #input color from user
        user_colors[position2] = usr_color #saving user color into a separate array
        position2 = position2 + 1



    print()
    print()

    #Result Engine

    user_c = 0
    user_c2 = 0
    

    for c in range(4):
        if user_colors[user_c] in colors: #Validate if the Color Entered is in the System Generated Color Array
            print('Color is Correct ' + user_colors[user_c] ) #Print the result
            user_c = user_c + 1
            found = True
        else:
            print('Color is incorrect.') #Print incorrect if color not in the systen array
            user_c = user_c + 1


    print()
    print()

    for v in range(4):
        if user_colors[user_c2] == colors[user_c2]: #Validate if the user input color position matches system color position
            print('Position is Correct for Color ' + user_colors[user_c2]) #print the result
            user_c2 = user_c2 + 1
        else:
            print('Position is incorrect: ', user_c2) #Position is incorrect if not same as system color array
            user_c2 = user_c2 + 1

    num_guess = num_guess + 1
    print()

print()
print('Number of Guess(s) Took You To Win: ', num_guess)
```

This is what I tried to implement in the `#userpart` but it's not working.

```py
user_colors = ['','','',''] #Array to store colors user guess
DisplayInfo()

while user_colors != colors:
    user_colors = ['','','',''] #This ensures that array is empty if user is retrying. Otherwise there will be an outofbound exception.
    position2 = 0
    should_restart = True

    while should_restart:
        for z in range(4):
            should_restart = False
            usr_color = input('Guess The Color: ') #input color from user

            if user_colors[position2] in colors:
                print("Wrong Color. Please Try again!")
                should_restart = True
                break

            user_colors[position2] = usr_color #saving user color into a separate array
            position2 = position2 + 1
```

Comment: try the for/else pattern https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html.

Comment: One immediate problem is that `position2 = 0` should be inside the `while should_restart:` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would design this by calling a function in a loop and raising an Exception for the invalid input case

You can also use a custom Exception for quitting or put the input into the exception string (allowing a user to escape with `Q/q`)

```py
def some_test_fuction():
    ...

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            some_test_function()
        except CustomException:  # you could use this to quit
            break  # or simply sys.exit()
        except ValueError:  # try to make the Exception as specific as possible
            print("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I simply added an hardcoded array of pre defined colors like

`pre_def_colors=['Red','Green','Purple','Yellow','Blue']`

I simply used a while loop with count and if color is present in the pre defined list, system will move on but if not, system will show an error and keep asking:

```py
#User Part

user_colors = ['','','',''] #Array to store colors user guess
DisplayInfo()

while user_colors != colors:
    user_colors = ['','','',''] #This ensures that array is empty if user is retrying. Otherwise there will be an outofbound exception.
    position2 = 0
    loop = 0

    while loop < 4:
        usr_color = input('Guess The Color: ') #input color from user

        if(usr_color in pre_def_colors):
            user_colors[position2] = usr_color #saving user color into a separate array
            position2 = position2 + 1
            loop = loop + 1
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid choice')
            continue
```